# How to check uniform continuity on disconnected set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ is function such that,

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases} n &\text{if $x=n, x\in\Bbb N$}\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and  $T= \mathbb{N}∪\{n+\frac{1}{n} | n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$

Then under usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$,  $f$ is uniformly continuous on

a) $\mathbb{N}$ but not on $T$

b)  $T$ but not on $\mathbb{N}$

c) both $\mathbb{N}$  and $T$

d) neither $\mathbb{N}$ nor on $T$

I get stuck on this question from hours, but didn't able to solve it.

I know function is always continuous on isolated points of domain if it is defined there, but point of $\mathbb{N}$ are not isolated point of domain $\mathbb{R}$. Further, $$\lim_{x\to n+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to n-} f(x)= 0≠ f(n)$$ so how can be function is continuous on points of $\mathbb{N}$? I may be wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

All function on $\mathbb N$ is uniformly continuous (due to the definition: Take $\eta = 1/2$ for any $\epsilon$).

$f$ is not uniformly continuous on $T$ since $|f(n+1/n)-f(n)| \to \infty$ while $|n+1/n - n| \to 0$.

Comment: Sir, I get about $T$ from your answer. But please could you elaborate about $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: now your previous answer will be correct, the original question changes to $T:=\Bbb N\cup\{n+1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}$

Comment: @Masacroso sir, please could you elaborate about the case for $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Lucas sir please tell me, how we get that $η = 1/2$? Because by definition of UC, for every x, y in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x-y| < η$ here x, y is in $\mathbb{N}$ then how $|x-y| < η$ ?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi  You just have to write the definition of UC: for all $\epsilon> 0$, there exists $\eta > 0$ such that for all $x,y$,  $|x-y| < \eta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. So if you take $\eta = 1/2$ then we always have   $|x-y| < \eta \implies x = y$ so it is clearly true that  for all $x,y$,  $|x-y| < 1/2 \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ since $|f(x) - f(x)| = 0 < \epsilon$ whatever $\epsilon$ is.